# Gradientmask for UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, blur, uivisualeffectview

I know that `UIVisualEffectView` ist very uncustomizable, so I can't setup the radius of blurness of the view or even the color.

Now I realized I could not even mask one.

I want to realize a Tabbar with blured Background, but to the top corner it gets sharper till 100%.
Because I know I couldn't adjust the blur radius I had the idea to work with a gradient mask to archieve something like this:

[image: Created with a graphictool]

But as sad at the beginning I could not even mask a simple Rectangle:

```
let gradientMask = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientMask.frame = effectView.frame

    gradientMask.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]

    effectView.layer.mask = gradientMask
```

The result is, the `UIVisualEffectView` doesn't show at all anymore.
Have you guy a workaround or something else?

EDIT: The view in the screenshot is for example, in the final app the background is a dynamic list with tiles where I can scroll through. So the workaround with snapshots will not work in my case.

Comment: I imagine this could be possible by making a runtime snapshot of the background `UIView` with the `UIVisualEffectView` effect and using the resulting snapshot image for display inside an overlaying `UIImageView` and applying the mask to that `UIImageView` while hiding the `UIVisualEffectView`. Not pretty but could work.
EDIT: Other than that, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595047/uivisualeffectview-with-mask-layer) might be related.

Comment: Good idea, but doesn’t work in my case. I forgot to say, my background will be dynamic. In the final view I will have a list where I can scroll through.

Comment: try to use gradient layer, instead of shape layer. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814922/how-to-apply-cagradientlayer-as-mask-of-another-calayer

Comment: or try this repo - https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView

Comment: @Kirow tried both, both with the same result. The blured view doesn't show up anymore. Tried it with blurView.mask = ... and blurView.layer.mask = ... For the mask I used a simple Rect layer, a CAGradientLayer and a UIView.

Comment: I guess to create this blur effect you need to work with masks and/or alpha channels internally. Because if you adjust one of that values the effect always disappears at all

Comment: @kuemme01 have you found a solution?

Comment: No sorry, I come to the end its not possible because of how UIVisualEffectView works.